# Matriz em Python - Maior valor da lista

Tags: python, matriz

Estou com dificuldade de resolver um exercício de matriz em Python, podem ajudar?

> **Descrição:** Uma loja com 4 filiais quer registrar a venda diária de cada filial pelo período de 1 semana. Crie uma matriz para armazenar as vendas. Escreva uma função que informe qual dia da semana teve o maior volume de vendas (incluindo as 4 filiais) e outra que retorne o número da filial que teve o maior faturamento semanal.

O que eu fiz até agora:

```
#Inserção dos valores para as matrizes 1x7, ja que são valores unitarios por dias da semana
loja_1=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
loja_2=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
loja_3=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
loja_4=[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]


def space():
    print('===========================================')

#Laço para inserção de valores da filial 1
for l in range(1):
    for c in range(0,7):
        loja_1[l][c]=int(input('\nDigite o valor das vendas por dia da semana, para a filial 1: '))

#Laço para formatar os valores da matriz da filial 1
for l in range(1):
    for c in range(0,7):
        print([loja_1[l][c]],end='')
    print()

space()

#Laço para inserção de valores da filial 2
for l in range(1):
    for c in range(0,7):
        loja_2[l][c]=int(input('\nDigite o valor das vendas por dia da semana, para a filial 2: '))
#Laço para formatar os valores da matriz da filial 2
for l in range(1):
    for c in range(0,7):
        print([loja_2[l][c]],end='')
    print()

space()

#Laço para inserção de valores da filial 3
for l in range(1):
    for c in range(0,7):
        loja_3[l][c]=int(input('\nDigite o valor das vendas por dia da semana, para a filial 3: '))
#Laço para formatar os valores da matriz da filial 3
for l in range(1):
    for c in range(0,7):
        print([loja_3[l][c]],end='')
    print()

space()

#Laço para inserção de valores da filial 4
for l in range(1):
    for c in range(0,7):
        loja_4[l][c]=int(input('\nDigite o valor das vendas por dia da semana, para a filial 4: '))
#Laço para formatar os valores da matriz da filial 4
for l in range(1):
    for c in range(0,7):
        print([loja_4[l][c]],end='')
    print()
```

Travei na parte: "Escreva uma função que informe qual dia da semana teve o maior volume de vendas (incluindo as 4 filiais) e outra que retorne o número da filial que teve o maior faturamento semanal."

Quando tento extrair o maior número da `loja_1`, apresenta erro informando que `list` não é iterável. Eu tentei converter `list` para `int`, usei `import heapq`, usei `max(loja_1)`, mas não consigo. Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro de tudo, você pode criar uma única matriz para armazenar todas as quatro filiais. Isso vai facilitará trabalhar com o valor das vendas das filiais já que elas agora não estarão separadas em variáveis. Além disso, será possível criar mais filiais sem precisar criar novas variáveis.

Para criar essa matriz, você deve juntar em uma mesma lista todas as filiais dessa forma:

```
lojas = []

for loja in range(5):

    vendas = []

    for dia in range(7):
        venda = int(input(f"Digite o valor de vendas da {loja + 1}ª loja no {dia + 1}º dia: "))
        vendas.append(venda)

    lojas.append(vendas)
```

Com o código acima, a matriz `lojas` deve ficar no seguinte formato (valores de exemplo):

```
[[20, 13, 2, 5, 6, 2, 4], 
[5, 7, 1, 8, 9, 11, 33], 
[4, 2, 21, 3, 4, 15, 3], 
[17, 34, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3], 
[6, 7, 4, 3, 45, 2, 2]]
```

---

Para obter o dia da semana com mais vendas, basta percorrer os dias e somar as vendas de todas as lojas nesse determinado dia. Depois disso basta comparar em qual dia vendeu mais.

Para fazer essa soma, você pode percorrer as linhas da matriz obtendo o valor da coluna referente ao dia dentro de um [List Comprehension](https://pythonacademy.com.br/blog/list-comprehensions-no-python) e somar os valores da lista retornada com [`sum()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sum.asp):

```
melhor_dia = [0, 0] # [vendas, dia_da_semana]

for dia in range(7):
    vendas = sum([loja[dia] for loja in lojas])

    if vendas > melhor_dia[0]:
        melhor_dia = [vendas, dia]
```

---

Para obter a loja com o maior número de vendas é bem mais fácil pois basta somar todos as vendas de cada loja com a função `sum()` e comparar os resultados. Veja o código abaixo:

```
melhor_loja = [0, 0] # [vendas, loja]

for loja in range(len(lojas)):
    vendas = sum(lojas[loja])

    if vendas > melhor_loja[0]:
        melhor_loja = [vendas, loja]
```